# Why give super weapons personalities?

Tags: science-based, weapons, artificial-intelligence

### Cover Story:

The minor arcana are four people, summoned from another world, that are prophesized to defeat the evil demon lord and bring peace and stability to this kingdom. Their weapons start out weak, but as they absorb new materials and defeat monsters; they unlock skills and become stronger in their respective fields. The four can rarely work together, however, as their weapons stall each other's progress when in close proximity.

### The Truth:

The minor arcana is a set of special-grade artifacts of the second type (artifacts that were created by combining several others through well-understood processes).

At their core is the fragment of a *Dragon's Heart*, a first-grade artifact, located in the bodies of mature dragons near their actual hearts. The *Dragon's Heart* is a semi-organic computer that serves as the weapons' framework, executing spells when needed, and analyzing new materials.

The *Dragon's Heart* inside these weapons came from a silver dragon who, while was a knowledgable, kind, and rather pacifist person, couldn't avoid getting betrayed and brutally murdered by his human "friend" who would later go on to make the minor arcana.

The artifact's most important attribute, however, is that the "hacker" Stands of the major arcana, namely, *Mephisto's Hanged Man* and *Martin's Hermit* can't take it over.

But there's a part I don't understand. The weapons need people to operate them, however, what these weapons do is they find a suitable host and then imprint their personality into it, they even have names:

- Naofumi (cups), The Impenetrable **Shield**
- Kaminari (pentacles), The Unstoppable **Spear**
- Kirito (**swords**), The Edgelord
- Kagome (wands), The **Bow**master of Helm's Deep

What's the problem?

I tell you what's the problem! The minor arcana are one of the few cases where incorporating artifacts into our technology raised their overall grade, but when these unhinged monkeys are handling them, they functionally get downgraded to level four or worse.

Naofumi frequently throws tantrums, Kaminari is even dumber than his comrades, Kirito can't stop bragging about how he's a HEMA master, and Kagome is a self-righteous "social bandit". In other words, they're horrible and horribly insecure people that shouldn't be put into the military.

**This is one of those design flaws where you have to put in extra effort to implement them, but why?**

There are plenty of people who are loyal enough that they don't mind using a weapon that was made from a desecrated corpse. Plus, if you're gonna imprint someone into the user, imprint competent people, so Mephisto wouldn't be able to compromise the team-integrity by blowing a rape whistle (yes, that's a reference).

As far as magic (which includes Stands) goes, it's basically nanomachines of different sizes and types doing different things. Usually, they need some time to do more complex/delicate things. Stuff like blowing things up is relatively fast (as the nanomachines act as suicide bombers) but has a limit on how many times it can be done before it needs to recharge.

In terms of power, the final forms of individual weapons are strong enough to defeat 50 men-at-arms.

Comment: I can't stop to note that, as artistically as the question has been turned into "magic/technology means", it's still a "story based" and "opinion inviting". Nice rule bending, tho', I won't V2C for this reason.

Comment: Impedance mismatch. It's like when you know you are a good engineer but you are forced into compromising compromises by your clueless (to engineering) manager. And since you cannot quit, you need to blow your steam from time to time, lest you explode.

Comment: I'm not sure how it follows that the devices having a personality requires "extra effort to implement [it]". Maybe it [just sort of happens and you don't know why](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/InstantAIJustAddWater). (Warning: TV Tropes link, not that you have anything better to do in isolation.)

Comment: @LiJun What? They imprint the same personality onto whoever they decide to be their host/wielder. Memories don't carry through though, but that can be a way to control the weapons.

Comment: uh....isnt thats what i mean? i dont remember mentioning carrying on the memory there? or you mean the weapon change the owner personality to be like the weapon bad personality?

Comment: @LiJun Yes, kinda like Anubis from JoJo.

Comment: ah....in that case wont it be just simply a middle finger by silver dragon then? since he get betrayed to become the weapon material, and sounds like this is first creation or more like prototype weapon to me. human is not perfect after all so its not surprising for its failure or unknown side effect upon first try.

Comment: Am I the only person who though of [Bomb number 20](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h73PsFKtIck) when I read that title ?

Answer (score 2):

- The shield is on a hair trigger. Permanently poised to react to an enemy attack. It is also the only one of the four with a defensive mission and feels frustrated that defense always gets "outvoted" by the other three.
- The spear is least concerned with feints. It pushes through and deals massive damage. It is not really dumb, it is focussed to a specific task to the exclusion of all others.
- By contrast, the sword fences and feints. The boisterous personality is all about befuddling an opponent, putting him on the defensive before the *duel* starts. Such antics would be pointless in a phalanx, so the spear doesn't have them.
- The bow provides covering fire to the other three. Self-righteous? No, it has the responsibility to look after them.

Answer (score 2):

It's to prevent the dragon from reforming.

A dragon's heart has a built-in defense mechanism. Left to its own device, over time, it will accumulate materials and recreate a full dragon.

Personalities are designed to keep the different parts apart, to make them antagonists, in order to prevent this. But the will to reunite and recreate the dragon is so strong that the weapons still seek each others out, creating conflict between them.

The unconscious goal of the weapons is to find bearers who are strong-willed and capable enough that they can be reunited.

Answer (score 1):

I see 3 options:

1: bad programming. Making these superweapons is tough, and personalities are even tougher. But what else are you going to do? You dont want someone greedy to keep their personality and wreak havoc with one of these! Be glad the personalities are at least somewhat useful. Personalities as a whole are useful as they give your Minor Arcana a drive to perform their duties.

2: limited space. four personalities, four designs that need to analyse it's surroundings and become more powerful with every battle all from a single silver Dragon's Heart? Even for one of these Dragon Heart's has limitations! Unfortunately you had to skimp on the personalities a bit to ensure the rest of these weapons would function properly.

3: hacking protection. The major Arcana can hack other minor Arcana and you needed some protection against this. A complicated network of safeguards, encryption and self-diagnostics runs throughout the entirety of the program as protection. Unfortunately this can limit the processingspeed of the personalities and/or pieces of the encryption and self-diagnostics can float the the surface of the personality. Due to the constant nature of these checks the personalities are continuously limited.